# Was bedeutet das Wort "Schanko"?

Tags: meaning, slang

Der Rapper GPC erwähnt das Wort "Schanko" in vielen seiner Lieder. Ein Beispiel ist:

> Ich bin kein Auto
>   Doch ich tu dir Schanko tanken.

[Quelle bei Youtube](http://youtu.be/IlNMukcVTfA)

Comment: Christ, danke schön für die Hilfe, doch es ist mir peinlich über meine Fehler.

Comment: Das muss dir überhaupt nicht peinlich sein. Dass Chanco Chantré + Cola sein soll, muss man nicht wissen!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nicht "Schanko", sondern "Chanco" = [Chantré + Cola](https://www.google.com/search?q=chantre%20cola%20chanco).

Comment: Yay!  Danke schön für die Antwort.